# Criticism of physics in _The Beginning of Infinity_?

Tags: multiverse

Have any criticisms been written of the physics presented in David Deutsch's book *The Beginning of Infinity*? Does he make any mistakes? If so, please refer me to them.

Comment: There seems to be an ongoing discussion about whether this question should be on topic, which I've [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41235/discussion-on-question-by-curi-criticism-of-physics-in-the-beginning-of-infinit) to allow it to continue.